# Showing the div dynamically on the even page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site where I need to add a 'menu' block on every page. I have an html code:

```
<div id="menuHead">
    <a href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logotype_850_250.jpg" width="auto" height="100%" align="left"></a>
    <a href="./index.html"><button class="menuButton">Search</button></a>
    <a href="./about.html"><button class="menuButton">About</button></a>
    <a href="./directs.html"><button class="menuButton">Directories</button></a>
    <a href=""><button class="menuButton">Support</button></a>
    <a href=""><button class="menuButton">Advertisment</button></a>
    <a href=""><button class="menuButton">Updates</button></a>
    <a href=""><button class="menuButton" id="helpB">Help the project</button></a>
</div>
```

So, how can I add this block on every page automatically using JS (jQuery)?

Comment: call ajax request and print result into desired div.

Comment: set this shole html code snippet into a JS variable. And then using jquery nd`append`method, put this on all the pages on `document.ready` event.\

Comment: If this is on every page, why not include it in the html or template...why bother to add it dynamically if there is no restriction rule? Do you want to add it on certain rule? Title says something and then in the description you say "every page"... What path do you want to take?

Comment: Dinca, on every. Sorry for title. My bad english))

Comment: I did it! Here is an error within the browser (localhost). Everything now is working perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery. 
Create a file called something like menu.html, and put your html of your   menu in there.
Then on every page where you want it to appear, create a div with the id       `menu`and add this javascript to your page.

```
<script> 
   $("#menu").load("menu.html"); 
</script>
```

Be sure to import jQuery in every page with the menu

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but it didn't work. It's showing nothing. White field. Maybe you know another way?

Comment: The answer you've linked is already mentioned in the comments. No need to copy paste it again.

Comment: I created an menuBlock.html and included it in #menuBlock. It's showing nothing

Comment: Now I'm trying to use it with an iframe. It works but I don't know how comfortable it will.

Comment: Stefan, look: i have an menuBlock.html. And I need to add this to the every page (one menu to multiple pages). Those code doesn't work, iframe is bad, i don't need a php. I have no ideas how to solve this a little problem)

Comment: Create a `<div>` and make the id menu. then add this code to your page      `<script> 
        $("#menu").load("menuBlock.html"); 
     </script>`

Comment: Stefan, okay. It works, but not fine. Now it shows me only a #menuHead div (written in menuBlock.html), but not a buttons and an image inside the div. What's wrong now?) Do I need an .appendChild(), and If yes - how to do this?)

Comment: Not sure why that would be, you can try to put the javascript code that loads the HTML into the div into a function that runs if the page is loaded: `$(function() {
   $("#menu").load("menuBlock.html");
});`

Comment: Stefan, it still doesn't show me a content in the div from the menuBlock.html. hmmm